# How to recursively change folder permissions on WAMP server

Tags: windows, recursion, permissions, directory, wamp

How do I change folder permissions recursively in Windows 7? Specifically, for my WAMP server, I want to change the permissions of my "www" folder so that its contents can be viewed over the Internet, and I want all of its subfolders to have the same permissions. Currently, for each folder, I'm getting the following message in my browser: "You don't have permission to access / on this server." I believe there's a simple command I could enter in a terminal for recursively changing folder permissions for global access; I just don't know what it is.

Comment: This is not a programming question.voting to move.

Comment: @rkosegi: It's not a serverfault question either as it doesn't relate to managing servers/networks or desktop infrastructure within a professional environment. WAMP servers on windows 7 really aren't within our scope unless the OP is trying to deploy them to a number of workstations a part of desktop infrastructure support and to be honest we'd expect someone doing that to know how to change file permissions.

Comment: @lain, ok, but is not programming question at all and superuser.com members can argue that managing/troubleshooting apache does  not belong there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object checkbox must be checked when changing permissions under Properties > Security tab > Advanced > Change Permission
Do this in the GUI to the parent folder.